# Wordpress Pagination change post per page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello Everyone I want to change the pagination posr per page. If page = 1 load 20 post. from page no. 2 to 100 I want to show only 10 post per page. I tried but not get any solutions. Here is my code.

````
$nmd_category = explode(',',$_POST['nmd_category']);
$nmd_channel = explode(',',$_POST['nmd_channel']);
if($_POST['pageNumber'] != 1){
            $num = 10;
            $c_name = '';
            $paged = $_POST['pageNumber'] ;
          }else{
            $num = 20;
            $c_name = 'first-load';
            $paged = 1;
          }
$args = array (
                'posts_per_page' => $num,
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'nmd',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                'paged'    => $paged,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'nmd_channel',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $nmd_channel,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'nmd_category',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $nmd_category,
                    ),
                ),
              );```
    Thanks in Advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code, that would help you:

Add this condition before query post

```
if($paged != 1){
  $postsperpage = 10;
} else{
  $postsperpage = 20;
}
```

and pass this post_per_page into query post like:

```
'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage,
```